# Android Studio Design Time Data Binding Fallback/Default value

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding

I am using Android data binding which works great:

```
<TextView
android:text="@{ee.Name}"
...
```

But if I do that the Android Studio designer doesn't show any text. Without text I can't see the TextView at all. Which is understandable because I haven't bound the data yet. Is there something like a fallback value or a default value which can be displayed until there is real data?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You should read the [Data Binding Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) posted on the Android developers website.
The last section of the document, [Android Studio Support for Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#studio_support) explain how you can use a placeholder that can help you during the design phase. It's very simple:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@{user.firstName, default=Placeholder}"/>
```

If you want to have text with spaces as placeholder you can use single quotes ('), back quotes (`) or `&quot;`

```
android:text='@{user.firstName, default="Placeholder text"}'
android:text="@{user.firstName, default=`Placeholder text`}"
android:text="@{user.firstName, default=&quot;Placeholder text&quot;}"
android:text="@{user.firstName, default=@string/placeholder_text}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exacly what I was looking for. I actually read this article you mentioned but didn't see that.

Comment: One thing I couldn't figure out is how to use that on colors. Something like: `android:background='@{ee.BackColor, default="color/colorPrimary"}'` -> `Failed to convert "color/colorPrimary" into a drawable`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I asked too soon. I figured it out. If anyone needs this: `android:background='@{ee.BackColor, default=@drawable/colorPrimaryD}'` + `<drawable name="colorPrimaryD">#FF627C1B</drawable>`

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Good luck on your projects!

Comment: What is the use of this when we already have the `tools` attributes?

Comment: For simple use cases just initialize variables during declarations to get default values!

Answer (score 15):

**The Preview pane** displays default values for data binding expressions.

```
android:text="@{user.firstName, default=PLACEHOLDER}"
```

This can set default value .

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@{defaultString ?? @string/hello_world}"/>
```

Comment: What is the benefit of this over the `tools:text` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see default value only at designtime, consider using [Designtime Layout Attributes](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes). This is useful if you for example want to put incorrect values (e.g. too long values) and see how it rendering, but you don't want to see it at runtime.

Of course, you can use both techniques - default placeholders (mentioned by @Bandreid) and designtime attributes. In this case you will see designtime attributes at designtime and placeholders at runtime.

Comment: I think this is not correct. The `default` attribute is only for preview and is not displayed at runtime.