# DataBinding not showing default value of textview

Tags: android

I am getting problem in data binding. In the application, the default value of `TextView` is not showing. `TextView` is just blank.

***XML File***

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDoctorName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text='@{doctorsInfo.name , default="FetchingData"}'
    android:textAppearance="@style/SuperHeadingText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Are you using any Binding Adapter for `text` atrribute ?

Comment: no i am not using adpter..

Comment: Anywhere in your Activity/Fragment, do you manipulate this `textView`, programatically ?

Comment: no, just on Api response I am binding. (mBinding.setDoctorsInfo(data);)

Comment: can you try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252516/android-data-binding-fallback-default-value] and tell me results .

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android:text='@{doctorsInfo.name, default="FetchingData"}'
```

**OR**

```
android:text="@{doctorsInfo.name, default=`FetchingData`}"
```

Instead of:

```
android:text='@{doctorsInfo.name , default="FetchingData"}'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have tried this one already but still not working

Comment: Have you check?

Comment: Add one more solution

Comment: Still same results :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
android:text='@{doctorsInfo.name, default="FetchingData"}'
```